# Affine Cipher decryption process wrong result

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have the problem when decrypting the text message. Example :

Plaintext  : "halo brother"

Ciphertext : "Å¾iÌ=ßOÌÅbO"

Plaintext  : "haﾌo｀bﾒothﾅﾒ"

k1 : 33 ->first key

k2 : 125 ->second key

I use ASCII printable & ASCII extended characters set total 224 characters.

Here is my code :

```
public class Affine {

//encyption method
public static String enkripsi(String pesan, int k1, int k2){

    //change text message into array
    char[] chars = pesan.toCharArray();

    //getting ASCII code from each characters index
    int[] ascii = new int[chars.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        ascii[i] = (int) chars[i];
    }

    //Affine encryption formula
    int[] c = new int[ascii.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < ascii.length; j++) {
        c[j] = ((k1*ascii[j])+k2) % 224 ;
    }

    //change the decimal (ASCII code) value back to characters
    char[] charen = new char[c.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        charen[i] = (char)c[i];
    }

    //change characters to String
    String pesan_en = String.valueOf(charen);
    return pesan_en;
}

 //decryption method
public static String dekripsi(String isipesanMasuk, int k1, int k2){
    int j,g;
    int[] c;
    int[] f = new int [224];

    //change text message into array    
    char[] chars = isipesanMasuk.toCharArray();

    //getting ASCII code from each characters index
    int[] ascii = new int[chars.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        ascii[i] = (int) chars[i];
    }


    //getting inverse from encryption formula of Affine
    //example 33f = 1 (mod) 224 -> f = (1+(224 * j)) / 5
    //g = (33 * f) mod 224
    //if g = 1 then stop
    for (j = 1; j < 224; j++) {
            f[j] = (1 +(224*j)) / k1;
            g = (k1*f[j]) % 224 ;
        if (g==1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    //Affine decrypion formula      
    c = new int[ascii.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < ascii.length; k++) {
        c[k] = (f[j]*(ascii[k]-k2)) % 224 ;
    }

    //change the decimal (ASCII code) value back to characters          
    char[] charde = new char[c.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        charde[i] = (char)c[i];
    }   

    //change characters to String
    String pesan_de = String.valueOf(charde);
    return pesan_de;
}   
    }
```

Comment: Which value did you use for `k1`? This can only work if `k1` is relatively prime to 224. In other words, it must not be divisible by 2 or 7.

Comment: Which value did you use for k2? Please give a working example so we can see where, what and how you call.

Comment: My k1 is random value of numbers relatively prime to 224

Comment: My k2 is random value from 0 to 223

Comment: No you give an actual example with the values you use. Only then we can experment with it. Something we can reproduce.

Comment: Here,
Plaintext : "halo brother",
k1 = 33,
k2 = 125,
Ciphertext : "Å¾iÌ=ßOÌÅbO",
Plaintext  : "haﾌo｀bﾒothﾅﾒ"

Comment: -1: Similar to providing a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please edit the question to narrow down the problem field: I see two possible causes, 1., your decryption isn't an inverse of encryption - if so only post the en/decryption part and leave out the SMS stuff -, or 2., your transmission isn't working correctly - if so only ask a question containing the SMS stuff and no encryption. You can check yourself which one it is by decrypting the message locally and verifying it is same as it was before encryption and comparing the sent message with the received msg.

Comment: Also, please post more readable code. I'm currently trying to reverse engineer what f and g in decryption are trying to achieve and I suspect it would be obvious if they had telling names and a few well placed comments.

Comment: I think my problem is in inverse of encryption, i have checked message locally and verifying it not same as it was before encryption. Can you help me??

Comment: @FebriansyahWahyudi: Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The decryption formula breaks down if `ascii[k]-k2` gives a negative value. To fix that use this:

```
c[k] = (f[j]*(ascii[k]-k2+224)) % 224;
```

Some other remarks:

you don't need an array to calculate the inverse of `k1`, a simple integer variable will do.

The encryption can result in control characters (\u0000 to \u000f and \u007f to \u009f) that might not be transported unaltered across all channels.

Comment: @FebriansyahWahyudi: To be honest I still don't understand how you calculate your inverse modulo 224 or if it even works for every `k1`. As an alternative to the current version you can just directly loop through every value 1<=inv<224 and test if it is the inverse (e.g. `int inv=0; for(int i=1;i<224;i++){if ((i*k1%224)==1) {inv=i;}}`) or use the extended euclidean algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: @Perseids It is not the most elegant solution but it works. If `(1 +(224*j))` is divisible by `k1` we have `f[j] * k1 = 1 + 224*j`. Taking the last equation modulo 224 it is clear that `f[j]` is the inverse of `k1`. Provided `gcd(k1,224)=1` there exists a `j` that works.

Comment: Thanks! With your help I would proof it like this: gcd(k,n)=1, 1≤k<n, 0<n => There exists 1≤f<n such that f*k = 1+n*j for some integer j. To proof 0≤j≤n-1: 1≤f*k≤n*n => 1≤1+n*j<n*n => 0≤j≤n-1. j=0 iff k=1. As 1+n*j is multiple of k, integer division by k yields f. I really wish we had LaTex math environments on Stackoverflow…